# SpringMVC: Could not instantiate property type [java.lang.Double] to auto-grow nested property path

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

We have an Input field that maps to

```
MyObject
 |--List<Double> tuition;
```

Upon binding the JSP field specific indexed elements of the list, e.g.

```
path="myobject.tuition[0]"
path="myobject.tuition[1]"
```

we get this error:

```
Could not instantiate property type [java.lang.Double] to auto-grow nested property path: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Double
```

But I thought all lists were auto-growable in SpringMVC? Can someone clarify?

**UPDATE** The Java Double class doesn't have a no-arg constructor, which is why it's failing. Very surprised it's not a more widely-known or discussed issue. How do you bind to Lists of classes like Double or Integer that don't support default no-arg constructors? Our only solution right now is to bind to a `List<String>` (Strings support no-arg construction) and then copy to a `List<Double>`, which is weird.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with changing your model slightly, you can wrap tuition into `Tuition` class:

```
public class Tuition {
    private Double value;
    /* getters, setters */
}
```

and then modify `MyObject` to:

```
public class MyObject {
    /* ... */
    private List<Tuition> tuitions;
    /* ... */
}
```

Changes to JSP:

```
path="tuitions[0].value"
path="tuitions[1].value"
```